# Simulating a single queue with multiple servers in Java

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I am trying to modify a program that simulates a single queue being served by a single server into a single queue being served by four servers. Here is the code for the single server situation:

```
public class SimulateSQMS {
final static int arrivalTimeLimit = 3600;
final static double arrivalProbability = 5.0/100;
final static int timeToServe = 15;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<Integer> queue = new Queue<Integer>();
    Random checkArrival = new Random();
    int timeLeftToServe = 0;
    int totalWaitTime = 0;
    int totalServed = 0;

    //
    // In the simulation, we simulate each second of time.  We continue the simulation until we reach
    // the time limit and the queue is empty.
    //
    for (int currentSecond = 1; currentSecond <= arrivalTimeLimit || queue.size() > 0; currentSecond++) {

        //
        // If the number of seconds has not exceeded the time after which no one is allowed to queue up,
        // check whether someone has arrived.  If so, put their arrival time on the queue.
        //
        if (currentSecond <= arrivalTimeLimit) {
            boolean arrivalHappened = (checkArrival.nextDouble() <= arrivalProbability);
            if (arrivalHappened) {
                queue.enqueue(currentSecond);
            }
        }

        //
        // If someone is currently being served, decrement the time remaining to serve by 1.
        //
        if (timeLeftToServe > 0) {
            timeLeftToServe--;
        }
        //
        // Otherwise no one is being served.  Check whether anyone is waiting on the queue and,
        // if so, begin serving them.  Add their wait to time to the total wait time and increment
        // the number served.
        //
        else if (queue.size() > 0) {
            int arrivalTime = queue.dequeue();
            int waitTime = currentSecond - arrivalTime;
            totalWaitTime += waitTime;
            totalServed++;
            timeLeftToServe = timeToServe;
        }
    }

    StdOut.println("Number served: " + totalServed);
    StdOut.println("Total wait time: " + totalWaitTime);
    StdOut.println("Average wait time: " + (double)totalWaitTime/totalServed);
}

}
```

Can someone please offer some suggestions as to how I could go about modifying this to account for four servers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace your int variable  timeLeftToServe by an array of 4 int. Here is the code :

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Random;

public class SimulateSQMS {
    final static int arrivalTimeLimit = 3600;
    final static double arrivalProbability = 5.0 / 100;
    final static int timeToServe = 15;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deque<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
        Random checkArrival = new Random();
        int[] timeLeftToServe = new int[4];
        int totalWaitTime = 0;
        int totalServed = 0;

        //
        // In the simulation, we simulate each second of time. We continue the
        // simulation until we reach
        // the time limit and the queue is empty.
        //
        for (int currentSecond = 1; currentSecond <= arrivalTimeLimit || queue.size() > 0; currentSecond++) {

            //
            // If the number of seconds has not exceeded the time after which no
            // one is allowed to queue up,
            // check whether someone has arrived. If so, put their arrival time
            // on the queue.
            //
            if (currentSecond <= arrivalTimeLimit) {
                boolean arrivalHappened = (checkArrival.nextDouble() <= arrivalProbability);
                if (arrivalHappened) {
                    queue.add(currentSecond);
                }
            }

            //
            // If someone is currently being served, decrement the time
            // remaining to serve by 1.
            //

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {

                if (timeLeftToServe[i] > 0) {
                    timeLeftToServe[i]--;
                }
                //
                // Otherwise no one is being served. Check whether anyone is
                // waiting
                // on the queue and,
                // if so, begin serving them. Add their wait to time to the
                // total
                // wait time and increment
                // the number served.
                //
                else if (queue.size() > 0) {
                    int arrivalTime = queue.poll();
                    int waitTime = currentSecond - arrivalTime;
                    totalWaitTime += waitTime;
                    totalServed++;
                    timeLeftToServe[i] = timeToServe;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Number served: " + totalServed);
        System.out.println("Total wait time: " + totalWaitTime);
        System.out.println("Average wait time: " + (double) totalWaitTime / totalServed);
    }

}
```

Have a Nice day.